# How can i get php script to return images to append to a div in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have been struggling with this for a while now and i have tried all kinds of ways but still can't append returned array to my div container, please can someone show me an example as i am loosing the will to carry on, i have had it working up until i found out that i could not use directory searching and was getting 403 error so now i am trying a new approach with php script.

```
<div id="content-container" style="height: 600px;">
<div id="content" style="height: 600px;">
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
  <h1> <span>The Gallery</span> </h1>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="" id="here">Gallery</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld01/">2014</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld02/">2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld03/">2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld04/">2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-albumid="images/gallery/fld05/">2015</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Back to home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="image-container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function () {
        var dir_path=$(this).data("albumid");
        LoadGallery(dir_path);
        return false;
    });
});

function LoadGallery(dir_path) {
$("#image-container").empty();

$.get('getimages.php', { dir : dir_path }, function(data) {
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
$(".image-container").append($("<a href='javascript:;' class='thumb'  data-src='"++"'><img src='"++"' title='Click to enlarge' alt='#'/></a>"));
});
}, 'json');
alert("ok");                
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$dir = $_REQUEST['dir'] ;

$filesArray = array(); 
$Counter = 0; 
$files = scandir($dir); 

foreach ($files as &$file) { 
if ($file!='.' && $file!='..' ) { 
    $filesArray[$Counter] = $file; 
    echo $filesArray[$Counter].''; 
    $Counter++;
}
} 

echo json_encode($filesArray); 
?>
```

Comment: do you see any error in console?

is your AJAX really sent to server?

do you see `ok` alert?

Comment: Are you sure this line, `echo $filesArray[$Counter].' '; ` is correct?

Comment: do a console.log(data) and add that to the question.

Comment: You have `$("#image-container").empty();` but then do `$(".image-container").append(....`? Is it `#image-container`(id) or `.image-container`(class)?

Comment: You are expecting `json` back -> `$.get('getimages.php', { dir : dir_path }, function(data) { ...[rest of your code]... }, 'json');` so your `echo $filesArray[$Counter]. ' ';` will cause an error. Remove that and just do your `echo json_encode($filesArray);`

Comment: Sorry about that, it is a class and the reason i have $("#image-container").empty(); is so that when the user selects a different set of images it loads them as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info and now i am getting this in my html, <div class="image-container">
<a class="thumb" data-src="undefined" href="javascript:;">
<img alt="#" title="Click to enlarge" src="undefined">
</a>

Comment: Your `src` is empty -> `<img src='"++"' title='Click to enlarge' alt='#'/>`. Try adding the `value` from your `$.each()` loop -> `<img src='"+ value +"' title='Click to enlarge' alt='#'/>`